# How to use wordpress shortcodes in custom php file?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-shortcode

I want to display wpdatatables(plugin) in my custom PHP file so I wanted to use "do_shortcode()" function but nothing works it just shows white screen.

my php file code:

```
<?php
    $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
    include_once $path . '/wp-config.php';
    include_once $path . '/wp-load.php';
    include_once $path . '/wp-includes/wp-db.php';
    include_once $path . '/wp-includes/pluggable.php';
    define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
    echo do_shortcode("[wpdatatable id=1]");
 ?>
```

Comment: check this  [Checklist](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/160504/110795)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think somehow you are not hitting correct page. Can you try to just echo something in that code? Even if shortcode isn't working you should get echo of [wpdatatable id=1] on screen.

If echo works, that probably means your shortcode isn't returning anything, so check that part also. E.g. create a new page from admin panel and try the shortcode.

Comment: echo is working and i tried with wordpress page shortcode is working

Comment: I tried your code with fresh wp installation and wpdatatables lite plugin and it's working fine. You may try to turn off all other plugins and change theme to default. But one more question: did you check your source code?

Comment: how did you make it to work i just reinstalled wordpress and tried again all i get is white screen and no errors. and which source code referring to?

Comment: It works for me, trust me. On blank page in browser press `ctrl+u`. Maybe it's not so blank.

Comment: now all i get is table heading and Generated by wpDataTables and no table is displayed but as u said i can see table's code in source code any idea why it is not displaying?

Comment: ps: just checked carefully table had style="display: none;" thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Turn on the debug mode, you will get a reason for the white screen. For example, put this code in your  wp-config.php and reload the page.

```
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
echo apply_filters( "the_content","[wpdatatable id=1]");
```

instead of do_shortcode() and see if that produces the output

Comment: (1) Try single quotes instead of double quotes (2) Check if error_log file has any errors logged (3) Try using some very simple shortcode and if that works, the shortcode you are trying to use is breaking the page output

Comment: tried using single quote didnt work and error_log was empty