# PHP do_shortcode in custom php file

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I've created a little bit of js that passes three variables to my php script loadtable.php. This php file is stored in my child theme folder and its contents are as follows:

```
<?php

$d = Date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_GET['d']));
$c = $_GET['c'];
$b = $_GET['b'];

$shortcode = "[wpdatatable id=3 var1=".$b." var2=".$d." var3=".$c."]";
echo do_shortcode('$shortcode');
```

The js part on the page:

```
window.onload = selectChart;

function selectChart () {
  var date = document.getElementById("date");
  var country = document.getElementById("country");
  var label = document.getElementById("label");
  var xDate = date.value.toString();
  var xCountry = country.value.toString();
  var xLabel = label.value.toString();

if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                 document.getElementById("chartTable").innerHTML = this.responseText;
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open('GET','/wp-content/themes/Avada-Child-Theme/loadtable.php?d='+xDate+'&c='+xCountry+'&b='+xLabel,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
```

I just can't get the do_shortcode php script to render the table when the page loads or when selectChart() is called. Do any of you know what my solution is? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have to import the wp-load.php file. 
require_once("../../../wp-load.php" );

And then echo do_shortcode('$shortcode');
I am not sure the code is working. 
echo do_shortcode("$shortcode");

Answer (score 0):

You should to use wordpress autoload first to be sure every necessary wordpress files like wp-config.php is loaded to your script and then use the wordpress function do_shortcode().

So your loadtable.php script should be something like this:

```php
<?php

require_once("../../../wp-load.php"); // wordpress autoloader

$d = Date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_GET['d']));
$c = $_GET['c'];
$b = $_GET['b'];

$shortcode = "[wpdatatable id=3 var1=".$b." var2=".$d." var3=".$c."]";
echo do_shortcode('$shortcode');
```

It works only when your script is in the root of your child theme folder. 
So if your script is located somewhere else, your path (../../../wp-load.php) should be changed.

Comment: Thanks! This got the script to work but it doesn't recognize the shortcode. Probably need to load something from the plugin as well I suppose.

Comment: @SVMN1 Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56560947/how-to-use-wordpress-shortcodes-in-custom-php-file Maybe it helps